# External touch screen for android

Tags: android, wpf, touch, multi-touch, kiosk

I have a 42 inch multi-touch monitor with IR Input. I want to develop applications for multi-touch input and I have planned to go with android. Is there any way to get touch input? when we go with WPF, have to depend on a PC. Im really confused how to go through!! please help me out.Is standalone monitor possible in ANDROID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it appears that the only option to get Android (at least under ICS) to include touch screen HID drivers is to recompile Android from source.

[Here are some instructions for exactly the purpose you describe](http://kafana.org/posts/pandaboard_android_ics/) (they also require [the PandaBoard](http://pandaboard.org) single-board computer as an intermediary).

[There's a guy on xda-developers who's trying to do this using the Android USB Host functionality and MHL only](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=30210471#post30210471) on a Samsung Galaxy S3, but there's no confirmation one way or the other that he ever got that working.